# How to copy files from the package to the main codebase?

Tags: makefile, build-process

I have got a plugin package to enhance the working of our product. This package contain some additional files and some modified main code-base repository files. But we can't directly merge this package with our code-base. Our target is to copy files from this package to the main code-base at the time of build. So we have to do some modifications in makefiles.

This package follows the similar directory hierarchy as that of the main code-base directory tree. What could be the best method to do so ? I'm thinking of creating some kind of script to do so. Would this be a good option ?

Comment: You could modify your makefiles to search for source files in the package tree first, before the main tree. If you show us the structure of your makefiles, we can give more detailed advice. Why can't you merge the package with your code base?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing any of your code, all I can suggest is creating a make target that will always get executed and putting it as part of the dependencies to your main code-base build. Something along these lines

```
final_target : other_dependencies copy_plugin_files
    command_to_build_final_target

other_dependencies : source_files
    command_to_build_other_dependencies

.PHONY : copy_plugin_files #this makes sure this will always execute

copy_plugin_files :
    [insert script or cp command here to copy your plugin files]
```

If you need the plugin files copied first, then put the `copy_plugin_files` dependency before the `other_dependencies` after `final_target`.

If you need the plugin files to run through their own make process first, then put `cd path/to/plugin && $(MAKE)` as part of the recipe for your `copy_plugin_files` target.

Hope that helps!

Comment: This was what I did finally. :)

Comment: But the problem with this that if in the version of plug-in new set of files are present then we need to re-write the Makefile.

Comment: If you are only looking in a certain directory for your new plug in files, then you could use the wildcard function like so `$(wildcard subfolder/*.c)`